# Tkinter: Understanding Columnspan effect on alignment

Tags: python, tkinter, alignment

I've been screwing around with some really basic grid commands in preparation for a project I want to do.  I'm shooting for a 2x3 grid where:

- Row one would have a button that spans the entire three columns.
- Row two would have two buttons.  One in column 2 and one in column 3.  (or 1,2 assuming we start at 0, but whatever)

My first step was just to setup everything and see it working.  Here's the main stuff:

```
b0 = Button(master, text = "Button 0")
b1 = Button(master, text = "Button 1")
b2 = Button(master, text = "Button 2")

b0.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
b1.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
b2.grid(row = 1, column = 2)
```

This worked as expected.

[Three buttons aligned like I expect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvNyj.png)

Next I tried to make the top button span two columns by changing this:

```
b0.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan=2)
```

And I got this...say what?
[Aligns row 1 and 2 on column 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8Waj.png)

Ok so what if we span 3?

```
b0.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan=3)
```

Yeah not what I expected...
[Centers Button 0, but doesn't maintain 3 columns properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TsC74.png)

So what am I missing?  How can I make Button 1 and 2 stay where they are in the first picture while expanding the Button0?  Ideally Button0 would be a label, but it doesn't seem to matter for explanation purposes.

For what it's worth I was just trying to mimic a yes/no or ok/cancel box where I could name the buttons whatever I wanted.  I didn't think the hard part would be aligning such a simple box.

[What I was trying to mimic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxQwe.png)

Comment: I suspect I could use frames to do this, but I feel like there's a simple elegant answer and I need to know what it is.

Comment: I think I understand what was missing.  I wasn't defining the root window size so it was just crushing everything in.

Comment: Add `master.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)` and set the initial width of `master` a bit bigger.

Comment: If you want to expand `b0` horizontally, use `sticky = 'ew'`. Or you can use `sticky = 'nsew'` to expand it in all directions.